# Combining 3 non equal access queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 unique queries that have many items in common. I am trying to create a combined query that includes blank cells where there is missing data.  So for example I have 3 dates with customer IDs and a unique number for one item, 4 dates with the same customer IDs and a unique number for another item, and 15 dates with the same customer IDs and a unique number for a 3rd item.  No matter how I try it, it's only returning the items with the same date - maybe I need to use a specific join in the code as opposed to in the GUI query view.

```
SELECT [20210209 Query].DESIGNATION, [20210209 Query].DATE,
       [20210209 Query].Item1, [20210209 Query-2].Item2, [20210209 Query-3].[Item3]
FROM [20210209 Query], [20210209 Query-2], [20210209 Query-3];
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Can you be more specific? Sample data would be useful.

Comment: Just trying to get around 10,000 records of data that sometimes lines up into a usable format... On the example above, the query is not returning all the records.

Comment: _the query is not returning all the records._ It does - and more, as you have no joins or filtering between the three tables. Thus, you have a _Cartesian_ (multiplying) query that returns all possible combinations of records from the tables.

Comment: Agreed, that was just the starting point.

Comment: I figured it out.  As I suspected, I had to manually code in a left join and that solved the problem.